# Is there a way to easy access api base url to link images?

Tags: api, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router

All my profile images are hosted on my api and  i'm using Vue for the frontend.
Whenever I want to display an image I import the api url from the **dotenv** file like so:

```
  const apiurl = import.meta.env.VITE_API_BASE_URL
```

...and then to link I use:

```
:src="apiurl+'/images/'+'whatever.jpg'"
```

Is there an easier/cleaner way to do this? like a global variable? or even using *vuerouter* to redirect image requests for api?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const instance = createApp(App);
instance.use(function (vue) {
  vue.config.globalProperties.apiurl = import.meta.env.VITE_API_BASE_URL
})
```

if use TypeScript  create index.d.ts;

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { Router, createRouter } from 'vue-router'
declare module "@vue/runtime-core" { 
  interface ComponentCustomProperties { 
    apiurl: string;
  }
}
```

in setup function

```js
import {
  ComponentInternalInstance,
  defineComponent,
  getCurrentInstance,
} from 'vue';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  setup() {
    const proxy = getCurrentInstance() as ComponentInternalInstance 
    const apiurl = proxy.apiUr
    
  },
});
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time, looks like a better solution. Also was studying the possibility of using provide/inject, do you see this as a better alternative?(doesn't let me upvote you due to the lack of reputation)